# Scala regex parser could not parse the result out

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-spark

I am new to scala, want to use the class RegexParsers to extract some important features

```
abstract class LogLine extends java.io.Serializable {
 def app: String
}
 case class AppSummary(timestamp: String, app: String, name: String, user: String, state:String, url:String, host: String, startTime: String, endTime: String, finalStatus: String) extends LogLine
 case class OperSum(title: String, user: String, operation:String,target:String,result:String, app: String, container: String) extends LogLine

 case object UnknownLine extends LogLine {
  val app = "unknown"
  }
object LogP extends RegexParsers with java.io.Serializable {
 def logline: Parser[LogLine] = (
   timestamp~"INFO   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId="~ident
    ~",name="~identW
    ~",user="~ident
    ~",queue=default,state="~ident
    ~",trackingUrl="~url
    ~",appMasterHost="~ident
    ~".icdatacluster2,startTime="~ident
    ~",finishTime="~ident
    ~",finalStatus="~ident ^^ {
   case t~_~app~_~name~_~user~_~state~_~url~_~host~_~stime~_~etime~_~finalStatus =>
     AppSummary(t, app, name, user, state, url, host, stime, etime, finalStatus)
}
 | timestamp~"INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER="~identY
    ~"OPERATION="~identY 
    ~"TARGET="~identY
    ~"RESULT="~identY
    ~"APPID="~identY
    ~"CONTAINERID="~ident ^^ {
    case t~_~user~_~operation~_~target~_~result~_~app~_~container =>
       OperSum(t, user, operation, target, result, app, container)
    } 
)
  val ident: Parser[String] = "[A-Za-z0-9_]+".r
  val identY: Parser[String] ="[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\s".r
  val identW: Parser[String] = "[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+".r
  val timestamp: Parser[String] = "2015-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9:,]+".r
  val url: Parser[String] = "http://[a-zA-Z0-1.]+:[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_/]+".r
}
```

it could work first case, but not second, for example: the following word:
**2015-03-09 01:36:39,016 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=pwalch OPERATION=AM Released Container TARGET=SchedulerApp RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1425682538854_0741    CONTAINERID=container_1425682538854_0741_01_000004**
could not be extracted. Hope sb. could help

Comment: Can you show us the "first case" that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible causes:

- You don't seem to be handling the whitespace between the `timestamp` and the string beginning `INFO` ?
- The string **AM Released Container** contains spaces, which your `identY` regex `"[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\s".r` is only going to match up to **AM** - so the subsequent matchers will all fail